# Select a table error: Range Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select part of a table.

To select the whole table, I found the first cell (e.g. A1) to the last cell (e.g. C10) of the table.

I thought I could save the range A1:C10  by the following code -

```vb
last_row = Activesheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
last_column = Activesheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).columnn

table = Activesheet.Range("A1:" & Cells(last_row ,last_column).Address)
```

The code is failing at the third line.
If I input `Cells(last_row ,last_column).Address` into the immediate window, it gives me the correct cell.
Is it because of the way I concatenated the range, and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `Set table = Activesheet.Range("A1", Activesheet.Cells(last_row ,last_column))`.

Comment: If there is only one table on the sheet `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Select`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrive the last row and column with UsedRange:

```
    last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    last_column = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'try this to determine the last column 
 LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```